# In Next.js after routing to a page, how can make auto scroll to a specific component

Tags: reactjs, next.js, scroll

In nextjs while navigating to different pages from a navbar section like:

```
 <Link className="dropdown-item" href="/about-rahim">Know Rahim</Link>
```

In this 'about-rahim' page, there are multiple components. After loading this page, how can I auto scroll to a specific components?

Comment: thank you @SeanW. but as my component was in different pages, that did not work...

Answer (score 2):

You can use the hash or query in the url to achieve this. Using the hash it can be done like this:

1.Add an id attribute to the component you want to scroll to and use it as the hash in the link:

```
<Link className="dropdown-item" href="/about-rahim#rahim-section">Know Rahim</Link>
```

2.In the target page (about-rahim.js), use the useEffect hook to scroll to the target component:

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';

function AboutRahim() {
  useEffect(() => {
    // Check if URL contains a hash (#) and scroll to the target element
    if (window.location.hash) {
      const element = document.querySelector(window.location.hash);
      if (element) {
        element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
      }
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      // Page content
     <div id="rahim-section">
      // Content to be scrolled to
    </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default AboutRahim;
```